# What is wrong with my Quartz cron expression? 6:30 Am, 9 AM, 12 PM, 2 PM

Tags: java, spring, cron, quartz-scheduler

I want my cron job to run exactly at the below times. I am using Java, Spring, and Quartz.

6:30 Am, 9 AM, 12 PM, 2 PM

I tried below, not sure if its correct. Please let me know if this is correct:

```
0 30,0,0 6,9,12 * *
```

Here's my Spring XML snippet:

```xml
<bean id="test" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean"> 
    <property name="jobDetail"> 
        <ref  bean="testjob"/> 
    </property> 
    <property name="cronExpression"> 
        <value>0 30,0,0 6,9,12 * * ?</value> 
    </property> 
</bean>
```

Comment: In that line you say it should run at 6:00, 6:30, 9:00, 9:30, 12:00, 12:30. You probably want to make 2 lines for that, one with `30 6 * * ...` and `0 9,12,14 * * ....`

Comment: would be good to get a bit more information - specifically the code that surrounds this. is it quartz or something else? are you using spring annotations. not all java crons are created equally.

Comment: I am using spring.org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean

Comment: ok but is it quartz for the cron? and is it annotation?

Comment: Its quartz for the cron.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you create these as 2 separate crons, one for the half past the hour ones and one for the on the hour ones.

so for `6:30 Am, 9 AM, 12 PM, 2 PM` create the following two...

```
0 30 6 * * ?
```

and

```
0 0 9,12,14 * * ?
```

Just to be sure you understand, you will need to create a **second** `CronTriggerBean` with the second cronExpression but you *can* reuse the job. The initial cron you tried would not work; you will need two cron expressions however you look at it.

Comment: +1 for the answer. Let me check if this works I will select this as answer. Thanks !

Comment: No problem, just to be sure you understand, you will need to create a second CronTriggerBean with the second cronExpression but you can reuse the job. The initial cron you tried would not work and could never work, you will need two cron expressions whatever you look at it :-/

Comment: +1, but your comment really ought to be in the main post to make sure future users see it. FIFY

Comment: @durron597 thanks, that makes sense. I will ensure I take more care in future.

Comment: @dectarin No problem, glad to see when lurkers begin to answer actively and well :)